# Synge's second variational formula for minimal submanifolds in Frankel's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In a paper I'm reading, the author proves the following generalized Hadamard theorem like this:

> [image]

> [image]

But I'm having trouble understanding this outlined result he uses without proof. How does this follow from Synge's second variation formula? I only know the second variation formula presented in do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry" book, and I don't know how that formula implies the one presented in this paper. How can I introduce the second fundamental form of these two submanifolds in the traditonal second variation formula (which I put below)?

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Up to different notations, this is a straightforward consequence of exercise 5 from chapter IX of do Carmo's "Riemmanian Geometry" book, which I'll attach below: [image]